# About sql server remote access

Tags: sql-server-2005

i am using sql server 2005.

my system is connected in network.

i want to give access to my sql server to specific person(IP) in the network and other persons should not access.

please solve this issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: "network" is LAN or WAN? If it is LAN, TomTom answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

It starts with reading the documentation.

- Give the user a login, protected by a password
- Grant this login rights to the databases the user should access
- Give user the login and password.

Finished.

Answer (score 0):

As TomTom indicated, the person will need a login. If both of you are on the domain (internal network), this is usually best accomplished by giving access to the person's Windows user account rather than a SQL Server login.

If you definitely need to restrict down to a specific IP, SQL Server has no built-in functionality for that. With SQL Server 2005 SP2 and greater you could build a logon trigger, but that can be problematic. Your best bet is to look into building an IPSEC policy that locks down your SQL Server access remotely to that specific IP address.